# Can't catch ActivationException with Prism NavigationAsyncExtensions 'RequestNavigate'

Tags: c#, .net, exception, navigation, prism

I am using Prism's `NavigationAsyncExtensions` method `RequestNavigate` on an `IRegion`:

```
// Attempt to navigate to the given view
try
{
    _mainRegion.RequestNavigate(viewName);
}
catch
{
    throw new MissingViewException(viewName);
}
```

I can pass a registered view name and get successful navigation. But when I pass an unregistered view name, I get an unhandled exception message on `RequestNavigate`. I expect for it to fail (I want to be able to catch the failure and throw a custom exception), but I can't catch the exception for some unknown reason:

[image]

I have tried a couple of alternatives:

1. Catch an `ActivationException` first.
2. Use `RequestNavigate` and pass a `navigationCallback`.
3. Use `RequestNavigate` and pass a `navigationCallback` (without a try-catch block).

None of the alternatives have worked. Does anyone have any ideas / suggestions? Thanks in advance! My gut is telling me that it is some type of threading issue, due to the extension method being asynchronous. But I figured the `navigationCallback` would take care of this and the result is sadly the same.